# elegant way to merge Map<String, List<String>> structure by using groovy

Tags: groovy, closures

I have a Nested Map structure:

```
Map<String, List<String>> case_pool = [
  dev : [
    funcA : ['devCaseA'] ,
    funcB : ['devCaseB'] ,
    funcC : ['devCaseC']
  ],
  'dev/funcA' : [
    funcA : ['performanceCaseA']
  ],
  'dev/funcA/feature' : [
    funcA : ['performanceCaseA', 'featureCase']
  ],
  staging : [
   funcB : ['stgCaseB'] ,
   funcC : ['stgCaseC']
  ]
]
```

and want to get result, when `branch.contains(case_pool.key)`, then merge the cases list. 
i.e:

```
String branch = 'dev/funcA/feature-1.0'

// will final get result of " 'dev' + 'dev/funcA' + 'dev/funcA/feature' ":
result: 
[
  funcA: [ "devCaseA", "performanceCaseA", "featureCase" ],
  funcB: [ "devCaseB" ],
  funcC: [ "devCaseC" ]
]
```

First I've using the loop:

```
String branch = 'dev/funcA/feature-1.0'
def result = [:].withDefault { [] as Set }
case_pool.keySet().each {
  if ( branch.contains(it) ) {
    case_pool.get(it).each { k, v ->
      result[k].addAll(v)
    }
  }
}
println 'result: ' + result
```

Secondly, I'm using the closure:

```
String branch = 'dev/funcA/feature-1.0'
def result = [:].withDefault { [] as Set }
case_pool.findAll{ k, v -> branch.contains(k) }.collectMany{ k, v -> v.collect{ c, l ->
    result[c].addAll(l)
}}
println 'result: ' + result
```

However, I don't like the way of `.collectMany{ k, v -> v.collect{ c, l -> }}`. Is there any better solutions? (i.e.: using `groupBy`, or something)

BTW, I've tried the `collectEntries`, and turns out the final List will replace all:

```
String branch = 'dev/funcA/feature-1.0'
println case_pool.findAll{ k, v -> branch.contains(k) }.collect{ k, v -> v}.collectEntries{it}

result: [funcA:[performanceCaseA, featureCase], funcB:[devCaseB], funcC:[devCaseC]]
```

the final `funcA : ['performanceCaseA', 'featureCase']` replaced the all `funcA: []`

Comment: The most confusing part for me is, that you are nesting collectMany/collect and then do a side-effect inside and throw away the result. I'd use `inject` instead.  Something along the lines of `result = case_bool.findAll{,,,}.inject([:].withDefault...}) { r, kv -> kv.values().each { c, l -> r[c].addAll(l) }; r }`

Comment: thanks @cfrick. I've tried your way `println case_pool.findAll{ k, v -> branch.contains(k) }.inject([:]) { r, kv -> kv.values().each { c, l -> r[c].addAll(l) }; r }`, and get issue: `No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.values() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cfrick says, an `inject` is better here, ie:

```
def result = case_pool.inject([:].withDefault { [] as Set }) { result, key, value ->
    if (branch.contains(key)) {
        value.each { k, v ->
            result[k] += v
        }
    }
    result
}
```

Comment: this way indeed better than the my secondly try.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the issue `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` [in Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/#technical-design), and even failed [by using @NonCPS](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps/#PipelineGroovyPlugin-2.14%28Sep07%2C2016%29).

Here are couples solutions:

1. keep using `inject([:].withDefault{})` which @tim_yates posted, just re-assign the `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` to `java.util.LinkedHashMap`:

   ```
   Map<String, List<String>> result = [:]
   case_pool.inject([:].withDefault { [] as Set }) { res, key, value ->
     if (branch.contains(key)) {
       value.each { k, v -> res[k] += v }
     }; result
   }.collect { k, v -> result[k] = v }
   ```
2. using `[].flatten().unique()`:

   ```
   Map<String, List<String>> result = [:]
   case_pool.collect { key, value ->
     if (branch.contains(key)) {    
       value.collect { k, v -> 
         result[k] = [result.getOrDefault(k,[]), v].flatten().unique()
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. using `findAll{}` + `collect{}`:

   ```
   Map<String, List<String>> result = [:]
   case_pool.findAll{ k, v -> branch.contains(k) }.collect{ k, v -> 
     v.keySet().each {
       result[it] = (result.getOrDefault(it,[]) + v[it]).flatten().unique()
     }
   }
   ```